# How to use property constraint in shortest-path on AgensGraph?

Tags: agens-graph

I tried to search shortest-path on two vertices.

But, there is a error on CYPHER query on mime.

How can I find shortest-path between vertices?

```
agens (AgensGraph 1.3.1, based on PostgreSQL 9.6.2)
Type "help" for help.

agens =# match p = shortestpath( (l1:l{id:1})-[:e*]->(l2:l{id:11111}) ) return nodes(p); 
ERROR:  property constraint is not supported
LINE 1: match p = shortestpath( (l1:l{id:1})-[:e*]->(l2:l{id:11111})...
```

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to use property constraint on older version of AgensGraph.

Think upgrading version of AgensGraph.

```
agens (AgensGraph 2.1.0, based on PostgreSQL 10.4)
Type "help" for help.

agens =# match p = shortestpath( (l1:l{id:1})-[:e*]->(l2:l{id:11111}) ) return nodes(p); 
                                               nodes                                                
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [l[4.1]{"id": 1},l[4.10]{"id": 11},l[4.91]{"id": 111},l[4.820]{"id": 1111},l[4.7381]{"id": 11111}]
(1 row)
```

If it is impossible, use "WHERE" clause instead of property constraint.

```
agens (AgensGraph 1.3.1, based on PostgreSQL 9.6.2)
Type "help" for help.

agens =# match p = shortestpath( (l1:l)-[:e*]->(l2:l) ) where l1.id = 1 and l2.id = 11111 return nodes(p);
                                               nodes                                                
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [l[4.1]{"id": 1},l[4.10]{"id": 11},l[4.91]{"id": 111},l[4.820]{"id": 1111},l[4.7381]{"id": 11111}]
(1 row)
```